# mapply with list of vectors as arguments to vectorize over

Tags: r, vectorization, apply, mapply

this is a general question about how (if possible) to use a named list (or other very generic solution) of arguments to vectorize over with mapply(). I am trying to find the correct pattern here so I can mapply() on a number of custom functions, without having to list the parameter names in the mapply() call. a simple example follows :

desired output following code not using list of arguments

```
mapply(seq, from = 1:3, to = 3:1)
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3 2 1
```

a (failed) attempt at the desired pattern :

```
from <- 1:3
to <- 3:1
vectorized_arguments <- list(from, to)
names(vectorized_arguments) <- c("from","to")
mapply(seq, vectorized_arguments)
      from to
 [1,]    1  1
 [2,]    2  2
 [3,]    3  3
 [4,]    4  4
 [5,]    5  5
 [6,]    6  6
 [7,]    7  7
 [8,]    8  8
 [9,]    9  9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `do.call` with `Map`

```
do.call(Map, c(f = seq, vectorized_arguments))
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3

#[[2]]
#[1] 2

#[[3]]
#[1] 3 2 1
```

Or `mapply`

```
do.call(mapply, c(FUN = seq, vectorized_arguments))
```

---

Or with `pmap`

```
library(purrr)
pmap(vectorized_arguments, seq)
```